# Disk space needed for installing Fuchsia OS toolkit?

Tags: installation, fuchsia

Following the directions on [Fuchsia > Get started](https://fuchsia.dev/fuchsia-src/development/source_code) appears to be working until it runs out of disk space. I am unable to locate any info on the amount needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mar'20, Source: 31.1 GB, after the build and setting up the emulator, QEMU: 102.9 GB:
[image: Source]
[image: After the build and setting up the emulator, QEMU]